# OpenFileDialog - expanding the left panel tree view

Tags: c#

I'm using `OpenFileDialog` to display a list of files to allow a user to select a file in a particular directory.

In my code I'm setting the `.InitialDirectory` to the path where the files reside. When I `ShowDialog()` the `OpenFileDialog` is displayed. The path at the top of the window matches the `InitialDirectory` path and the files I'm interested in are displayed in the right panel.

The issue I'm having is that the left panel is not expanded. The panel is just showing `Local Disk (C:)`. I would like to expand view to match the `InitialDirectory`. Is there a way to expand the tree view to display the path shown on the top of the `OpenFileDialog` box without drilling down to it once the `OpenFileDialog` is opened.

Comment: What framework version and OS are you on?

Comment: The user is in control of this, not a program.  Pushing your preferences onto the user is never not a mistake, Windows gives you a hard time about it intentionally.  Just do it on your own machine, Control Panel + Folder Options, "Automatically expand to current folder" option.  Ask at superuser.com if you don't see it, you must mention your Windows version.

Comment: On my machine (W8.1, 64bit) and Winforms (VS13) the tree pane does expand to show the Initialdirectory. And amazingly enough it also scrolls down to show the Initialdirectory right at the top line. Just as it should. I could swear this was different last year. @Hans: I beg to differ: If I open a filedialog, then I should be in control of what it shows and how, not the user. I should be able to control the user's choices as much as I think necessary. The options  the dialog gives to the user (incl deleting things) can be a real problem imo..

Comment: You can differ till your face is blue.  This is up to Microsoft engineers, not me.

Comment: Hehe, my face is alright. But it was you who wrote: _Pushing your preferences onto the user is never not a mistake_ and while usually true, I think in this context I rather trust the programmer..    Anyway, the real question is: how did the behaviour change? I know I often had a hard time when the InitalDirectory was shown at the bottom of the list.

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using Windows 7 and 4.5 .NET framework. Sorry about that! Thanks for the input. I will try setting the folder options.